# How can I overwrite a whole file with the content of another?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, multiple-files

I have two tabs open, file1.txt and file2.txt, each with different content.

How can I copy the whole content of file1.txt and overwrite file2.txt with it, resulting in both files having the same content.

This is obviously doable with yanking manually, but I figured there's probably a nice combo that does it all in one go.

**Edit** : Based on [Rich's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17727/19461), I ended up doing this :

```
" SplitOverwrite()
" Yanks all content of the current window and pastes it 
" into the adjascent window, overwriting all existing content
function! SplitOverwrite()

    " Yank the whole file content
    %yank

    " Move cursor to the window right
    wincmd w

    " Delete the whole file content
    %delete

    " Puts the text from register O after the current line
    put 0

    " Deletes the first (empty) line of the file
    1delete

    " Save the file
    w

    " Short version
    "%y|winc w|%d|pu0|1d|w

endfunction

nnoremap <leader>so :call SplitOverwrite()<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this unholy ex command in your first tab:

```
:%y|tabn|%d|pu0|1d
```

It’s certainly a combo that does it all in one go, but is it nice?

That’s a rhetorical question: it’s clearly not.

### Further details

This is a maximally abbreviated version of the following sequence of commands:

- `:%yank`: Yank the entire file by using the `:yank` command with the `%` range. (See `:help cmdline-ranges`.)
- `:tabnext`: Move to the next tab.
- `:%delete`: Delete the entire buffer by passing the `%` range to the `:delete` command
- `:put 0`: Put the contents of the yank register (See `:help "0`) after the current line.
- `:1delete`: The commands above will leave a blank line at the top of the file. We can remove this by passing a different range to the `:delete` command. (N.B. A previous — less efficient — version of this answer instead used `norm!ggdd` to remove this line by using the `:normal` command to emulate typing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.)

These have been consolidated into a one-liner by using a `|` character to run multiple commands on a single line. (See `:help :bar`).

You can view the documentation for each of these commands by inserting them into a `:help` query. e.g. `:help :yank`.

Comment: I think after the `:put` you need to delete the first line

Comment: I do delete it! (You might need to refresh the page? The original edit left a blank line at the *end* but I’ve fixed that by making it even uglier.)

Comment: a true, did not see it

Comment: That's plenty nice for me! I'm trying to figure out what each step does. Would it be possible to modify it to work with splits instead of tabs ?

Comment: @mike23 Sure! Try replacing `tabN` with `wincmd w`. I’ll update the answer with some more explanation when I get a minute.

Comment: All right, it works with split windows now :) I ended up putting your command in a function, which I remapped to a key combination (mapping the command right away threw an error). Learning vim is really exciting !

Comment: @mike23 Isn't it! If you're (sensibly) putting it in a function, I'd thoroughly recommend a). typing out each command name in full b). putting them all on separate lines, instead of joining them together with `|` characters.

Comment: @mike23 You might like to watch [this video](https://vimeo.com/15443936) (one of my two all-time favourite Vim videos) for a terrific example of the power/flexibility of ex commands.

Comment: Just watched the video.. mind blown.

Answer (score 4):

based on @Warren's answer, there are actually two other alternatives

1. running from the source file: `:w !cat > dest_file`  (note the space between `w` and `!`, which runs an external program and uses the content written as `stdin`)
2. running from the destination: `:%! cat < source_file` (this uses filter and the contents of the destination is discarded since the external program redirected its input)

Answer (score 3):

From the `file1.txt` buffer, say `:w! file2.txt`.

Then either:

1. In the `file2.txt` buffer, say `:e!` to manually reload that buffer with the new content.
2. Use one of the "autoread" plugins to make Vim do this automatically and reliably: [[1](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5206)] [[2](https://github.com/djoshea/vim-autoread)]

Comment: This gives me a `E139: File is loaded in another buffer`

Comment: @mike23 Use two Vim instances.

Comment: how about `:w !cat > file2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Another version that uses functions more and avoids messing up the registers

```
function! SplitOverwrite()

    " get the whole file content
    let x = getline(1, '$')

    " Move cursor to the window right
    wincmd w

    " Delete the whole file content to black hole register
    %delete _

    " set the contents
    call setline(1, x)

    " Save the file
    w
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>so :call SplitOverwrite()<CR>
```